# He mocked me for not speaking clearly - did "not speaking clearly" really happen ? or it is just a thought?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> He mocked me for not speaking clearly.

Does this mean I did not speak clearly?

Or

Does this mean he thought I did not speak clearly which does not tell whether in reality, I spoke clearly or not?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence obviously says nothing at all about whether your speech was unclear as a fact generally agreed upon.

Context would obviously change this.

> The microphone was defective, and Tom mocked me for not speaking clearly

implies that there was a factual basis for the mockery.

> Everyone but Tom congratulated me on my speech; he mocked me for not speaking clearly

implies that either everyone one else but Tom lied politely or else Tom is a captious jerk.

Sentences seldom exist without a context, and context affects plausible meanings.

Answer (score 0):

He mocked me for not speaking clearly.

**Does this mean I did not speak clearly?**

Yes, indeed, it does.

He laughed at me for not speaking clearly.

Same thing. You did not speak clearly.

for not x provides a reason for the main verb.

He mocked me for spending too much money.

Same thing. The reason I was mocked was for spending too much money.